# Plot multiple dataframe in a plot with facet_wrap

Tags: python, python-ggplot, plotnine

I have a dataset `df` that looks like this:

```
ID      Week    VarA    VarB    VarC    VarD
s001    w1      2       5       4       7
s001    w2      4       5       2       3
s001    w3      7       2       0       1
s002    w1      4       0       9       8
s002    w2      1       5       2       5
s002    w3      7       3       6       0
s001    w1      6       5       7       9
s003    w2      2       0       1       0
s003    w3      6       9       3       4
```

For each ID, I am trying to plot its progress by Week for all Var (VarB,VarC,VarD) with VarA as the reference data.

I do `df.melt()` and run coding below and it works.

```
ID     Week  Var  Value
s001    w1  VarA    2
s001    w2  VarA    4
s001    w3  VarA    7
s002    w1  VarA    4
s002    w2  VarA    1
s002    w3  VarA    7
s001    w1  VarA    6
s003    w2  VarA    2
s003    w3  VarA    6
s001    w1  VarB    5
s001    w2  VarB    5
...
```

Codes:

```
for id in idlist:

#get VarA into new df
newdf= df_melt[df_melt.Var == 'VarA']

#remove rows with VarA so it won't be included in facet_wrap()  
tmp = df_melt[df_melt.Var != 'VarA']

plot2 = ggplot() + ggtitle(id) + labs(x='Week',y="Value") \
    + geom_point(newdf[newdf['ID'] == id], aes(x='Week',y='Value')) \
        + geom_point(tmp[tmp['ID'] == id], aes(x='Week',y='Value',color='Var')) \
           + theme(axis_text_x=element_text(rotation=45))

print(plot2)
```

However, when I add `facet_wrap('Var', ncol=3,scales='free')` I get an error below

```
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

And also I couldn't connect the line using `geom_line()`.

This is my expected output:
[image]

Is this because of the different `df` used? Is there a way to use multiple `geom_point()` for different df and `facet_wrap` in one ggplot object?

Comment: Try resetting the index. `newdf = newdf.reset_index()` and `tmp = tmp.reset_index()`.

Comment: @has2k1 nothing changed and still got the same error

Comment: Then I would need a copy-pastable example to tell what is wrong!

Comment: @has2k1 i have put my current codes and `df` in my question so what do you mean by that?

Comment: I would need to be able to run it easily.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @has2k1 i have put it on colab here: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1p0UwK-At5QzRfC0lKcC5EBP4r0lFoWf_?usp=sharing

Comment: You are hitting a bug. I have created a minimal reproducible example, [here](https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/issues/647).

Comment: Make this a reply so I can mark as answer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with the question is a bug that would be reproduced by the following code. The bug has been [fixed](https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/issues/647) and the next version of plotnine will have the fix.

```py
import pandas as pd
from plotnine import *

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': list("abc"),
    'y': [1, 2, 3],
    'g': list("AAA")

})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': list("abc"),
    'y': [4, 5, 6],
    'g': list("AAB")
})

(ggplot(aes("x", "y"))
 + geom_point(df1)
 + geom_point(df2)
 + facet_wrap("g", scales="free_x")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the fixed bug as mentioned by @has2k1, I have found the solution to add a reference data point `VarA` by renaming the column name of `Var` to something else so that both `df` do not have the same column name and will allow `facet_wrap` to work only on one of the `df`.

```
for pt in idlist:
    #get VarA into new df
    newdf = df_melt[df_melt.Var == 'VarA']
    newdf.rename(columns = {'Var':'RefVar'},inplace=True)

    #remove rows with VarA so it won't be included in facet_wrap() 
    tmp = df_melt[df_melt.Var != 'VarA']

    plot2 = ggplot() \
        + geom_point(tmp[tmp['ID'] == pt],aes(x='Week',y='Value',color='Var')) \
        + facet_wrap('Var',ncol=1,scales='free') \
        + geom_point(newdf[newdf['ID'] == pt],aes(x='Week',y='Value'))  \
        + labs(x='Week',y='Value') + ggtitle(pt) + theme(axis_text_x=element_text(rotation=45),subplots_adjust={'hspace': 0.6})

    print(plot2)
```